# Add option to select with php

Tags: php

I want to add the following option to my existing selectbox, if the 'total_of_groups' is not 0.

```
 <option value="groupmembers" <?php echo selected('groupmembers',bp_profile_visibility_get_settings($user_id,'bp_profile_visibility' ));?>><?php _e('Group Members Only','bp-profile-visibility');?></option>
```

Unfortunately it doesn´t work. I´ve tested the code snippet outside the select and it works perfect.

```
            <select  name="bp_profile_visibility">
                <option value="public" <?php echo selected('public',bp_profile_visibility_get_settings($user_id,'bp_profile_visibility' ));?>><?php _e('Everyone','bp-profile-visibility');?></option>    
                <option value="friends" <?php echo selected('friends',bp_profile_visibility_get_settings($user_id,'bp_profile_visibility' ));?>><?php _e('Friends Only','bp-profile-visibility');?></option>    
                    // the new option //
                    <?php
                    $is_groupmember = BP_Groups_Member::get_group_ids( bp_displayed_user_id() );
                    $total_of_groups = $is_groupmember[total];
                    if( $total_of_groups != 0 )             
                         echo <option value="groupmembers" <?php echo selected('groupmembers',bp_profile_visibility_get_settings($user_id,'bp_profile_visibility' ));?>><?php _e('Group Members Only','bp-profile-visibility');?></option>
                    ?>                  
                <option value="self" <?php echo selected('self',bp_profile_visibility_get_settings($user_id,'bp_profile_visibility' ));?>><?php _e('Only Me (private)','bp-profile-visibility');?></option>    
            </select>
```

Comment: When you say "doesn't work", what specifically is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't put quotes around your `echo` statement, and you are already inside a php block. Try this:

```
if( $total_of_groups != 0 )             
    echo '<option value="groupmembers" ' . selected('groupmembers',bp_profile_visibility_get_settings($user_id,'bp_profile_visibility' )); . '>' . _e('Group Members Only','bp-profile-visibility') . '</option>';
```

Comment: o.k., if delete the last ";" I get no server error, but the option in the selectbox is still blank.

Comment: the problem is the language-part "_e". If I change it with for e.g. "print_r" it works and the option is not blank, but the translation doesn´t work.

Answer (score 0):

o.k. I found the solution by myself:

The translation part must begin with "__" and not with "_e".

```
echo '<option value="groupmembers" ' . selected('groupmembers',bp_profile_visibility_get_settings($user_id,'bp_profile_visibility' )) . '>' . __('Group Members Only','bp-profile-visibility') . '</option>';                    ?>
```